# datatable deleting rows deletes multiple rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I am trying to delete a row from a datatable after an ajax call is successful. The rows in the table represent events that the user 'accepts' or 'rejects'.

The DataTable is created with an asp:Repeater:

```
<table id="dtTriage">
    <tbody id="tbodyT">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptT" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr class="odd gradeX" id='raw<%#Eval("eventId") %>'>
                    <td class="td-triage">
                        [...]
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

then in the function triggered by the accept or reject button I do an ajax call as such:

```
var dtTriage = $('#dtTriage').DataTable();
var row = $('#dtTriage tbody tr[id=raw' + eventId + ']')[0];
$.ajax({
    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/User/Services/WebServices.asmx/SaveEventPreferences") %>',
    data: params,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;",
    success: function (message) {                    
        dtTriage.fnDeleteRow(row, null, true);
    }                              
});
```

Now this works fine if the user presses the button once; but if he presses it multiple times before the ajax call returns a success, the row gets deleted as well as rows below it (as many as you press); Im confused as to why this happens: I delete that specific row (by its eventId).

Any clarifications would be much appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: add a flag while ajax is in process and this flag should forbid re-calling delete while ajax is in progress, then once ajax completes reset this flag

Comment: Thank you @Nikos M. , for now I simply disabled the button on click; but I just wanted to understand why the following rows get also deleted even though I delete a specific row according to a unique ID